# Null-Coalescing Operator in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following expression which can be an empty string in some cases

```
@item.Creator
```

And I tried to represent it as follows in Razor View page but it is not giving me what I expect. 
This is how I wrote the code

```
@item.Creator ?? Unknown
```

Expecting that in cases where the Creator is an empty string that I would get "Unknown" in its place. However, on the contrary, I get the following:

> ?? Unknown

in the page as output. 
I am obviously missing something on how to apply this operator in Razor View and I will appreciate any guide to correct it.

I am working with ASP.NET-Core 3.1 on C# 8 on a windows machine
thank you

Comment: try @(item.Creator ?? "Unknown")

Comment: I was facing the same issue in my HTML button and changed like below and worked ,
 <button type="button" class="btn @(item.IsAvailable ? "disabledbtn" : "")" id=@item.Id>
                                                        @item.StartTime
                                                    </button>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implicit-razor-expressions):

> With the exception of the C# await keyword, implicit expressions must not contain spaces.

Use an explicit expression instead:

```
@(item.Creator ?? "Unknown")
```